Gulp pattern matching - match all scss files
My test function looks like:
function taskBuildStyles() {
  let path1 = 'Amtsverwaltung_Achterwehr/Web/styles/source/web_v1.scss';
  let path2 = 'Amtsverwaltung_Achterwehr/Web/styles/source/*.scss';

  return src(path2)
    .on('data', function(file) {
      console.log('File found:', file.path);
    })
}

If I set path1 as a parameter, I get the output 'File found' in the console. However, if I set path2, I don't get any output. This needs to work for any scss file. This worked on version 4, but after upgrade on version 5 does not work as expected.
